# Determinant of Matrix with uncomputable values.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> Calculate the determinant of the matrix
>   $$
> \begin{pmatrix}
>   10^{10} & 10^{10^{10}} & 11^{11^{11}} & 1 & 0 \\
>   2^{2^2} & 3^{3^3} & 7^{7^7} & 0 & 1 \\
>   11 & 17 & 12 & 2 & 7 \\
>   2 & 3 & 5 & 1 & 1 \\
>   9 & 14 & 7 & 1 & 6 \\
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$

[image]

My wonderful Russian Professor put this one up on the board. Obviously it's not something one can put in Wolfram Alpha. I can't see any obvious linear dependencies between rows or columns, I've tried assigning variables to the big values (just for ease of notation) and doing row operations, transposing to get it into upper triangular it all still ends in a mess.

Now, I know our Prof HATES computation and is terrible at it, so he wouldn't write this up unless there is some structural simplicity I can't see...?

Comment: just going to take a wild guess and say it's 0.

Comment: @djechlin I wasn't seeing the 2nd element of the 5th row as a 14... the answer is dependent on it.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Is there a reason why some of the ones in your determinant are underlined?

Comment: @MartinSleziak Sorry, I normally write everything in TeX. I didn't write this, it's literally a photo I took of the whiteboard from class. I can delete the question if you want?

Comment: @BenjaminR If that's the case, it is perfectly fine. But I could not have known that. (You may have noticed that many users take a photo of their own handwritten question instead of typing the question. And, well, this definitely is not a photo of a blackboard, so maybe the assumption that this might be your handwriting was not entirely impossible.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Hint: look at the sum of the last two rows.

Comment: Is the fact that your professor is Russian ... so determinant ?

Comment: @JeanMarie 

Comment: Ah, R3 = R4 + R5!

Comment: This is assuming, of course, that the element at $\alpha_{52}$ = 14. My problem was I thought it was an 11 or 17...

Comment: It does not look at all like how your prof writes 1's and 7's (though in fairness, the prof's 1's are not all consistent: probably the result of being away from Russia too long!).

Comment: Said Prof got back to me and confirmed it is indeed a 14.